# Create pandas duplicate rows based on the number of items in a list type column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
  df
  col1     col2
   A        [1]
   B        [1,2]
   A        [2,3,4]
   C        [1,2]
   B        [4]
```

Now I want to create new rows based on the number of values in the col2 list where the col1 values will be same so the final data frame would look like,

```
  df
  col1    col2
   A       [1]
   B       [1]
   B       [2]
   A       [2]
   A       [3]
   A       [4]
   C       [1]
   C       [2]
   B       [4]
```

I am looking for some pandas short cuts to do it more efficiently

Comment: I think dupe was wrong (partly only), so reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and then create one element lists:

```
df2 = df.explode('col2')

df2['col2'] = df2['col2'].apply(lambda x: [x])
```

Another idea, I hope faster in large data is use numpy `np.repeat` with `chain.from_iterable` for flatten values:

```
from  itertools import chain

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        "col1": np.repeat(df.col1.to_numpy(), df.col2.str.len()),
        "col2": [[x] for x in chain.from_iterable(df.col2)]})

print (df2)
  col1 col2
0    A  [1]
1    B  [1]
2    B  [2]
3    A  [2]
4    A  [3]
5    A  [4]
6    C  [1]
7    C  [2]
8    B  [4]
```